# Restore time for deleted site

Tags: sharepoint-online, restore

One of my colleagues accidentally deleted a Sharepoint Online Site. We were able to recover the site from the recyle bin but when we now visit the site it's saying that you need to request access to it, even the site owners who still are set as owners on the if you look on their access levels get's the same message.

how long will it take for the page to be restored if that's an issue or is there something else you need to do?

Also: is there anyway to find out which user deleted the site in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific time for the restoration process, it mainly depends on your site size

> If you are talking about the site  retained time it's 93 days

Answer (score 0):

It may take a while and there may be a time delay to restore a site, you just need to wait.
Currently, it seems that finding out who deleted the site is impossible.

A similar thread for your reference:
[How can I find out who deleted my Site Collection in SharePoint Online 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89913/how-can-i-find-out-who-deleted-my-site-collection-in-sharepoint-online-2013)
You can also try to restore a site using PowerShell.